# split integer multiple values in one field into rows in ssis

Tags: c#, ssis

Please help me split column's field values into multiple rows.

Table

```
ID        Name                Location        DeptNo

1         Jack                 Florida        101,102,103
```

I'm looking for output like this

```
ID        Name                Location        DeptNo

1         Jack                FLorida         101
1         Jack                FLorida         102
1         Jack                FLorida         103
```

I've figured out the configuration in ssis using script component but not sure about my code

Please check

```
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{

    int[] Edpt = Row.DeptNo.ToInt().Split(new int[] { ',' }, IntSplitOptions.None);

    int i = 0;

    while (i < DeptNo.Length)
    {
        Output0Buffer.AddRow();

        Output0Buffer.ID = Row.ID;
    Output0Buffer.Name = Row.Name;
        Output0Buffer.Location = Row.Location;
        Output0Buffer.DeptNo = DeptNo[i];

        i++;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I've done something similar using VB. Not sure if this helps, but I've also included the following vb code as two additional subs. This works for me. I presume there must be something similar in C? `Public Overrides Sub PrimeOutput(ByVal Outputs As Integer, ByVal OutputIDs() As Integer, ByVal Buffers() As Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.PipelineBuffer)
        MyBase.PrimeOutput(Outputs, OutputIDs, Buffers)
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Sub CreateNewOutputRows()
    End Sub`

Comment: Use a SQL Query for the Source component that employs a Split() function to output the rows you want.

Answer (score 3):

99% of the way there.

Given a source like

```
SELECT
    1 AS ID        
,   'Jack' AS Name
,   'Florida' AS Location
,   '101,102,103' AS DeptNo;
```

Your Script task becomes Asynchronous as it will not be a 1:1 input to output buffer. I made 3 changes to your script.

The first was in the creation of edpt array. There might be a way to split the strings and convert the result directly to a nullable integer array but it didn't come to mind.

```
    string[] Edpt = Row.DeptNo.Split(new char[] { ',' });
```

The second changes was your for loop. `while (i < DeptNo.Length)` is going to look at each character in the source DeptNo string. so you'd have something like 11 output buffers created (which would then fail when it attempts to put the comma into an integer (unless it treats it as a char data type and then uses the ascii value). At any rate, to heck with while loops unless you need them. The `foreach` helps eliminate the dreaded off by one mistakes. So, I enumerate through my collection (Edpt) and for each value I find, I assign it to a loop scoped variable called `item`

```
    foreach (var item in Edpt)
```

The final change is to the assignment in my output buffer. `Output0Buffer.DeptNo = DeptNo[i];` again would only be access a specific value in the original string (1, 0, 1, ,, 1, 0, 2, ,, etc). Instead, you want to operate on the splitted array like `Output0Buffer.DeptNo = Edpt[i];` But, since we don't need to do any of that ordinal access, we just reference `item`.

```
        Output0Buffer.DeptNo = Int32.Parse(item);
```

The final code looks like

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    // Create an array of the department numbers as strings
    string[] Edpt = Row.DeptNo.Split(new char[] { ',' });

    // no longer needed
    int i = 0;

    // foreach avoids off by one errors
    foreach (var item in Edpt)
    {

        Output0Buffer.AddRow();

        Output0Buffer.ID = Row.ID;
        Output0Buffer.Name = Row.Name;
        Output0Buffer.Location = Row.Location;

        // use the iterator directly
        Output0Buffer.DeptNo = Int32.Parse(item);
    }

}
```

[image]